# Dual boot results with "hd1 gpt2 not found"

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive, uefi

I have two new exactly the same ssd disks.

On one of them I installed windows 10, and next on the second one Ubuntu 20.04.

Everything was perfectly fine, after some time restarting the computer made the disks dissapear. Several next restarts made it work again.

Few days later again both disks disappeared. I used live cd ubuntu to check what happened and seems like nautilius can see these disks and they are fine.

I did grub repair, and tried just reinstalling the grub but only ubuntu is working now. Selecting windows in grub menu gives me this kind of error: `device not found. hd1 gpt2 not found` or `hd0 gpt2 not found`. It looks pretty random, sometimes it says hd0, sometimes hd1.

I found many similar topics but I really don't understand what these people talk about.

Could you please help me out?

`fdisk -l` results:

```
    Disk /dev/loop0: 54,97 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 97,1 MiB, 101724160 bytes, 198680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 30,29 MiB, 31756288 bytes, 62024 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 161,42 MiB, 169254912 bytes, 330576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 255,58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 54,97 MiB, 57618432 bytes, 112536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 25,12 MiB, 26333184 bytes, 51432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 62,9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 223,58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: CT240BX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0A651799-E4FC-4DAB-9394-16B19B2D88F9

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1085439   1083392  529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2  1085440   1288191    202752   99M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1288192   1320959     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1320960 468860927 467539968  223G Microsoft basic data




Disk /dev/sdb: 223,58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: CT240BX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe5ff8554

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb2       1052670 468860927 467808258 223,1G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1052672 468860927 467808256 223,1G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/loop8: 96,52 MiB, 101191680 bytes, 197640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 332,84 MiB, 348983296 bytes, 681608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 49,8 MiB, 52203520 bytes, 101960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 43,16 MiB, 45248512 bytes, 88376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 332,9 MiB, 349048832 bytes, 681736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 255,58 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 29,84 MiB, 31272960 bytes, 61080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: It looks like you have sda installed on a GPT partition table formatted disk, and sdb on a MBR (dos) partition table formatted disk. Normally you should install both using the same. GPT/UEFI or MBR/BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema thank you for your comment! This is the default way these systems were installed. I am not very advanced user so I let the setup do the job itself usually

Comment: Did you install a fresh partition table on sdb before the Ubuntu install?

Comment: @heynnema Honestly, I have no idea. I took two fresh disks, installed first windows on one, after it was done and fully updated I installed newest ubuntu on the second one and also kept it fully updated. Everything was working for weeks before this started happening. I did not select any advanced settings on ubuntu install. Just selected the drive and let the setup manager do the rest

Comment: Have you run boot-repair yet?

Comment: @heynnema yes i did boot-repair and also reinstalled grub2 several times

Comment: If it was me, I'd backup anything important from sdb, then from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB I'd use `gparted` to lay down a fresh GPT partition table on sdb (this will wipe the drive), and then reinstall Ubuntu on sdb. I think that GRUB is getting confused between the two. Have good Windows backups first. This all assumes that your computer is set to UEFI, not BIOS.

Comment: Let me know how you make out, and if it all works, I'll do a formal answer for you, ok?

Comment: @heynnema i did open live cd and created new gpt table on sdb using gparted. Now windows started working. Thank you!

Comment: So is it all working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Normally, on UEFI computers, disks are formatted with GPT partition tables (mandatory on disks 2TB or larger).

Normally, on multi-boot computers, operating systems are installed the same way, that is, UEFI/GPT, or BIOS/MBR.

You had your Windows SSD (/dev/sda) as GPT, but your Ubuntu SSD (/dev/sdb) as MBR. This caused GRUB to get confused.

- Backup your important Ubuntu AND Windows files
- Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- Start `gparted`
- Install a fresh GPT partition table on /dev/sdb (this will wipe the drive)
- Quit `gparted`
- Reinstall Ubuntu on /dev/sdb